# Bar plotting with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I came across a code on SO which I can't seem to find the link to, but the answer contained this solution to plot the number of occurrences for a specific date format:

```
date_value = df['TIMESTAMP']
m = date_value.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H'))
x=m.value_counts()
x=x.sort_index()
x.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

The `lambda` breaks it into every hour. Is it possible using the same code, or something similar, to do it at different intervals (i.e. every 6 hours)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the timestamp column is your index, you can use `resample`, for example, to count the number of observations over six hour intervals:

```
df.set_index('TIMESTAMP').resample('6H', how='count')
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to resample a pandas DatetimeIndex

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))

ts.resample('100D').plot(kind='bar') # many options on the re-sample period
plt.show()
```